# Frequency of letters pairs at position in string

Tags: python, frequency

I have a text file with a list of strings like:

```
ALFLLNSYLTTL
DYLLHGDDKSLN
SLLADESADSHR
YMVNLNDELYNN
```

I need to write a script in python which will determine the frequency of each letter in each respective position.

For example in the first position A,D,S,and Y each occur once so the frequency for each is 25%. Then for the 3rd positions F,L, and V each occur with L occurring 2 out of the four times so the frequency is 50%.

In addition I need to repeat this with frequency for each observed pair. For example the frequency of AL in the 1st and 2nd positions.

I am new to python and don't really know a lot of the syntax and functions that could help me complete this task.

Comment: Hint: use `enumerate` and `collections.Counter`, and if you are allowed to use it, the pandas library will have great functions for this sort of stuff.

Comment: Also try `zip` across all lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` and `collections.Counter` to calculate the frequency of letters by column. Use `numpy` to transform the file content to 2d array which can use multiple dimension slice. And use `Counter` to count the frequency of each unique letter.

```
import numpy as np

from collections import Counter

with open("text.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as text:
    lines = [list(line[:-1]) for line in text.readlines()]

lines = np.array(lines)

# for first question

for i in lines.shape[1]:

    counter = Counter(lines[:, i])

    for key in counter.keys():

        print key, counter[key] / lines.shape[0]

# for second question

counter = Counter(lines[:, 0:2])

print counter["AL"] / lines.shape[0]
```