# Filtering out correct data from set of coded text values

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, filtering, prediction

I am interested in developing a small script that can either use predictive analysis to filter out garbage characters from a set of similar strings.

Data is received from multiple sources at once, and the number can vary from 1-10 sources at a time. Each source sends over their version of the data but sometimes in transmission values get mixed up.
Example:
4 sources return the following data:

xbcd
abbd
$acf
abdf

The correct value that would be initially transmitted is: abcd, however due to transmission data is mutated.

I'd like to figure out a predictive system or even AI based that can take the dynamic input and compare each character to others and figure out the most common repeating character to return a prediction.

I have done this using recursion that compares each character to their corresponding index in the other set however it will become time consuming as there's over 100 different sets of data coming in every second and it has to run on one machine parallely. The number of characters will increase in the future and I'd like to know if there's any optimized solution that can be applied that is quicker than recursive comparison.

The final value is compared later on to a mathematically estimated value, however I would prefer not to run a database check each time the value has to be checked, this is only run in the case if all data is received incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds ambitious, but it might help if you can give more details about the constraints.  is it synchronous, with data arriving from each source at each designated time point?  In your example you give 4 groups of 4 letters, so there is some ambiguity--is each source trying to measure/transmit the same latent value 'abcd'?  What is the range of possible values--strings of any length containing any ascii characters?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can count the frequency of each letter in each string position using `numpy` and `collections.Counter` as described in a previous answer to [Frequency of letters pairs at position in string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44815743/16327476).

The most frequent, 'modal' letter in a particular position across a single set of samples could be your best guess at the latent letter for that position at that point in time.